# repeat command with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a repeat command with discord.py where you send in a command and it repeats the message you sent in. It works, but the only problem is that if I use spaces, for example "Hello I'm" it only prints out "Hello". How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```py
import discord
import hypixel
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready to use!")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(718088854250323991)
    await channel.send(message)

bot.run('Token')
```

Comment: The problem is that there is only one argument. Arguments are spaced out by spaces, so if you write hello there, it thinks that there is only one argument which is hello. Fix this by doing async def send(ctx, *, message).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, NEVER show your bot token publicly, this way anyone can write code for your bot and make it do whatever that person wants.

As to your question,
If you call the command with `Hello I'm`, it'll only return `Hello`. This is because, in your send function, you are accepting only one argument.

Thus, if you send `Hello I'm` it's taking only the first argument passed to it which is `Hello`. If you call that command again but this time with quotes, `"Hello I'm"` for example, it will return `Hello I'm`.

The solution for this would be changing your send function to something like this, which would take an arbitrary number of arguments and then join them together:

```py
async def test(ctx, *args):
    channel = bot.get_channel(718088854250323991)
    await channel.send("{}".format(" ".join(args)))
```

Which would join all the arguments passed to it and then send that message.

As shown here [Official Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Alternative: Using Keyword-Only Arguments:
This can also be done as:

```py
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(718088854250323991)
    await channel.send(arg)
```

Again, referring to the official docs at [Keyword-only arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Discord changed his/her bot's token already. I think Discord crawls the web and looks for bot tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Just write it like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def yourcommand (ctx,*,message):
    await ctx.send(f"{message}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```py
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, *, message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(718088854250323991)
    await channel.send(message)
```

This allows you to set multiple values into that same message. A better way to do this is:

```py
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, *, message:str):
    channel = bot.get_channel(718088854250323991)
    await channel.send(message)
```

This will ensure that the message value will be turned into a string. Always a good habit, because you don't know if you might make a typo and use it as another data type.

Answer (score 0):

ah this is easy

```py
@client.command()
#* for infinite args
async def echo(ctx,*,args:str):# it will turn every thing into a str like echo hi , hi will be a str automatically 
    await ctx.send(args)
```